# Redis cluster on kubernetes: how service knows which are masters for write?

Tags: redis, cloud, cluster-computing

Redis cluster on kubernetes: how service knows which are masters for write?

```
                               PODs
   Jedis(client) -- service -- Redis Master A
                            -- Redis Slave B
                            -- Redis Slave A
                            -- Redis Master B
```

Write operations(e.g., set) need to go to a master. But how the service know which are masters?

Comment: How are you deploying redis? Perhaps there is a separate service that only selects the master pods.

Comment: https://www.airplane.dev/blog/deploy-redis-cluster-on-kubernetes. The service is regular k8s service that does not have knowledge about master/slave. All the pods are treated as the same.

Comment: Looks like the service doesn't discern between reds master and the other nodes. The article itself prescribed execing into the pod and setting the key-value pairs directly from there. Can you check if writing key-value pairs to the service meets with an error when not written to the master?

Answer (score 0):

> Redis cluster uses a form of composite partitioning called consistent hashing that calculates what Redis instance the particular key shall be assigned to. This concept is called a hash slot in the Redis Cluster. The key space is partitioned across the different masters in the cluster. It is split into 16384 slots, effectively setting an upper limit for the cluster size of 16384 master nodes (however, the suggested max size of nodes is in the order of ~1000 nodes).

I believe, Redis calculates [hash slot](https://severalnines.com/blog/hash-slot-vs-consistent-hashing-redis/) of the given key and determinates master node.

You can read more about redis [key distribution model](https://redis.io/docs/reference/cluster-spec/)